# JSzip "generateAsync" not working on Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, jszip

I want to download and save a collection of PDFs in a single ZIP file using "JSZip" ver. 3.2.1 and "FileSaver" of 24-Jan-2014 working with all latest Browsers on Windows 10 64bit.

This is on Windows 10 and using Internet Explorer 11, Edge, Canary, Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, but not Safari.

I have some sort of compatibility issue with the "**generateAsync**" function on Internet Explorer 11, which is the only one browser my code is not working on.

I collect the PDFs using [**Ajax**] and put them all in a single ZIP file one by one, but the moment it comes to the "generateAsync" it fails only on IE.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Ajax
var zip = new JSZip();          // JSzip

xhr.responseType = "blob";
```

I execute the Ajax with its own methods :

```
xhr.open("GET", filepath[i], true);
xhr.send();
```

the "xhr.onreadystatechange" in executed for each Ajax call to PDF.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
  if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4)
  {
    PDFdata = xhr.response;
```

"filename[i]" is an array filled with the PDFs filenames.

```
    zip.file(filename[i], PDFdata, {blob: true});
```

until here it is all working smooth, I have the PDF filename and its data stored in the ZIP file.

```
  }
}
```

when PDFs are over, I go straight to the SAVE :

```
zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then
(
  function(content)
  {
    saveAs(content,fn);
  }
);
```

but here comes the issue : it seems that the "**zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then**" make Javascript fail working only on IE11 somehow.

If I put an [alert] before and inside the function, I have only the 1st one responding but not the 2nd one:

```
alert('STILL WORKING...');

zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then
(
  function(content)
  {
    alert('CANNOT REACH THIS POINT!');

    saveAs(content,fn);

    alert('DOES NOT EVEN KNOW IF IT SAVE WITH SUCCESS ON IE11');
  }
);
```

there is something in the "**zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then**" that is disliked by IE.

I confirm that every other Browser I have used is way more tolerant about this procedure and poses no problems at all, but since there is always someone that is found of the old IE at my work-place, the only thing I could do until now is to suggest them to use Chrome or Edge in place of IE.

My question is : "Is it possible to make JSzip fully working on IE11 ?" or do I have to open and debug the [js] source files and try to find a way in?

Comment: Is your file size is very big after adding all the PDF files in zip file? If yes than it can be possible that your code meets with any limitation of JSZip. I suggest you to make a test with one or two files which has small size to check whether it works or not. Reference: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/limitations.html

Comment: Alas it is not the filesize the problem, JSZip does not start to save the archive on IE, no matter how many files are in there (even with only 1 small pdf); it is a problem strictly bound to Internet Explorer only, with other Borwsers I can create archives with 500+ documents, even if takes time to be completed.

Comment: To me it seems that IE Javascript may be a bit too primitive today and the JSZip.generateAsync does not work with its limitations; If so, the only ways left are to use a different Browser oredit the JSZip source file and make the correct patches for IE compatibility.

Comment: I suggest you to contact to JSZIP support and confirm about this limitation with IE. They did not mentioned anything clearly in their limitations page. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll do that soon with this same post.

Comment: did you try confirmed the issue with the JSZIP team? If yes, can you please try to update the status of the issue. We can check whether we can provide any help from IE side and it will also helpful to other users who will have similar issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: sorry but I've not yet contacted JSZIP Devel Team because I'm working now on a different Project fulltime and this issue is easily solved by using a different Browser.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know about the status for the issue.

Comment: How do I change its Status?

Comment: I mean thanks for informing us. If we talk about the issue than it will be good to contact  JSZIP team. they can give the hint if there is any compatibility issue with IE.